# PHP file_exists returns true but createimagefromjpeg runs in an error

Tags: php, stream, file-exists

I have a really strange error!

Here is my code:

```
if (file_exists($this->template->large_image_location)) {
    $tmp_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->template->large_image_location);  

    //work with $tmp_src
} else {
    //no picture there                      
}
```

I cannot reproduce the error but some Users say that they get the following error message:

> ErrorException [Warning]:
>   imagecreatefromjpg(/srv/.../.../.../th_vorschau_123.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory!

Why can I even get this error? I prove the file with `file_exists` in front of trying to load the image!

Comment: You need to catch and debug when that happens. After `$tmp_src = imag..` put `if ($tmp_src === false) { log all possible variables that you have to a file }` so you can debug information later.

Comment: ok i just implement the truepath function in the answer from shankar but this doesn't work really fine at the moment! if i'm not able to start this one working for me and other developers in office i will give the debugging way a try! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Glavic is right. But sometimes **`realpath()`** leads to problem. So make use of this function. **[Tested]**

```
    <?php
function truepath($path){
    // whether $path is unix or not
    $unipath=strlen($path)==0 || $path{0}!='/';
    // attempts to detect if path is relative in which case, add cwd
    if(strpos($path,':')===false && $unipath)
        $path=getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path;
    // resolve path parts (single dot, double dot and double delimiters)
    $path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    $parts = array_filter(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path), 'strlen');
    $absolutes = array();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if ('.'  == $part) continue;
        if ('..' == $part) {
            array_pop($absolutes);
        } else {
            $absolutes[] = $part;
        }
    }
    $path=implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $absolutes);
    // resolve any symlinks
    if(file_exists($path) && linkinfo($path)>0)$path=readlink($path);
    // put initial separator that could have been lost
    $path=!$unipath ? '/'.$path : $path;
    return $path;
}

if (truepath('redarrowdown.gif')){
    $tmp_src = imagecreatefromjpeg(truepath('redarrowdown.gif'));

    //work with $tmp_src
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "fails";
    //no picture there
}
```

Comment: I never had problems with `realpath`; what kind of problems did you have?

Comment: Sometimes i get false boolean data.

Comment: tested with readarrowdown.gif ?? :D gif would not have worked! 

thanks i will test this today!